# Does anyone have an updated guide for installing node-xmpp?

Tags: xmpp, node-xmpp

Does anyone have an updated guide for installing node-xmpp from start to finish on either Cent OS or Ubuntu's latest builds?

I have attempted installing but continue to get the following error:

```
Cannot load StringPrep-0.1.0 bindings. You may need to `npm install node-stringprep'
```

This is the log for stringprep:

```
root@node-xmpp:~/node-latest-install# npm install node-stringprep
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-stringprep
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-stringprep
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-stringprep/-/node-stringprep-0.1.5.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-stringprep/-/node-stringprep-0.1.5.tgz

> node-stringprep@0.1.5 install /root/node-latest-install/node_modules/node-stringprep
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/node-latest-install/node_modules/node-stringprep/build'
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/node-stringprep/node-stringprep.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/node-stringprep.node
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/node-stringprep.node: Finished
COPY Release/node-stringprep.node
make: Leaving directory `/root/node-latest-install/node_modules/node-stringprep/build'
node-stringprep@0.1.5 node_modules/node-stringprep
```

Comment: Not releated to the question but just wanted to share that, I am trying on windows to install node-xmpp but it appears that it does not install on it. Let me know if anyone has tried doing that.. I was following a tutorial on how to create a google chat bot with nodejs.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly this problem installing node-xmpp on a Fedora 17 system.

The solution for me was **yum install libicu-devel**

**libicu** "provides Unicode and Globalization support for software applications" and I guess the up-to-date version of this is needed by node-xmpp.

See https://github.com/astro/node-stringprep

Answer (score 0):

I've exactly this problem installing node-xmpp on a Debian 6 system.
I use `apt-get install libicu-dev`, I've upgrade node, follow this issue https://github.com/astro/node-stringprep/issues/32 but the problem is not solve